# Can we use Resource Expressions in javascript and other parts except Literal?

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-3.5, app-globalresources

The **Literal control** works all the time

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal7" runat="server" 
    Text="<%$ Resources:ErrorMessages, errorCompanyNotFound %>" />
```

But if I want to use this as a **parameter** in an image, like

```
<img src="blahblah" alt="" 
    title"<%$ Resources:ErrorMessages, errorCompanyNotFound %>" />
```

It gives the annoying error

> Literal expressions like '' are not allowed. Use instead.

Same happens if I try to access it through **Javascript**

```
var noHit = '<%$ Resources:ErrorMessages, errorCompanyNotFound %>';
```

---

Does anyone had **any idea** how can I fetch the Global Resource value under this circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I could find to work correctly was to use a public method instead the `<%$` call.

in code behind I did:

```
public string GetResource(string ResourceName, string ResourceKey)
{
    string r = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(ResourceName, ResourceKey) as string;
    if (r == null)
        return ResourceKey;
    return r;
}
```

then was as easy as call it:

```
<img src="blahblah" alt="" 
    title"<%= GetResource("ErrorMessages", "errorCompanyNotFound") %>" />
```

and

```
var noHit = '<%= GetResource("ErrorMessages", "errorCompanyNotFound") %>';
```

*I hope this helps someone like me* :)

Comment: Actually, you can just use the built-in `GetGlobalResourceObject` method instead of your custom method.  If you have Resharper 5, it'll even give you intelliense on it.

Comment: This will only work if you embed all the javascript that needs to be localized in your ASPX page which for a variety of reasons, performance, reuse, etc. isn't ideal. If you're using .js files you'll need another solution.

Comment: @Heliar what I do is have a `<script>` area with all the variables in the page, then I load all `.js` that will call those variables, works pretty well! PLus you can create your own dynamic javascript that will create that file for you and load it before all others. This is a common use.

Comment: I use a similar technique for server side items, current culture, certain paths, etc. but I try to encapsulate them into a single global object which is less evil than global variables. Resources I think I want to do differently, either a handler/module or probably a better option, pre-generated js from a T4 template or the like.

Comment: T4 templates were not that good back in 2010 when this answer was written ;)

Answer (score 0):

For html controls, not MS ones like `asp:Label`, you need to add `runat="server"` in order to access the resources value.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-xs" runat="server" value="<%$ Resources:GlobalResources, resMyValue %>">
```